# keeping 0 after coverting double to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying tie convert a double to string after some calculations but when I get a number like 439.0 it converts the number to 439 after the toString function. I need to keep the .0 as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
variable.ToString("F1")
```

the F1 causes you to display 1 decimal. This is the shortest way to do it that i know of :)

You can display more decimals by changing the 1 to 2-3-4 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [The `"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with 1 precision with a culture that has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
var d = 439d;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // prints 439.0
```